# How to change the Decimal point in Node Editor

Tags: node-editor

How to change the Decimal point in Node Editor

I can just change only First decimal place everytime

I got this

[image]

[image]

But i want this

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess you are changing it by clicking arrows? You can get any value you want, if you'd place cursor here and type a number

Answer (score 2):

Hold down *Shift key* while grabbing the input value with the mouse cursor. So you can edit up to three decimal numbers.